# Audio recording from multiple sources (MIC input and System Output)

Tags: android, audio-recording

Seems like currently the [`AudioCapture`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) module only allows to capture audio from single source (using [`setAudioSource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioSource%28int%29)) which most probably is MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC by default.

I need to record from multiple sources. MIC input and System Output(media player) to be precise. Is this at all possible (using the stock rom and kernel) ? If yes, what would be the best way to achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.